# Can I create a sharepoint hosted app for office 365

Tags: office-365

All i want is a app for office 365, which will create a sub web using a button, can i create a sharepoint hosted app and upload it to office 365 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes, you can create a SharePoint hosted app for Office 365.

Comment: thanks, how to deploy it to office 365 ?

Comment: Specify the Url of the O-365 site while creating a SharePoint hosted app in Visual Studio. Press F5 to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of basic SharePoint hosted app http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379